# Passing multiple parameter using '?' mark in web urls

Tags: url, web

http://xyz.com/packagesearch**?**cadu1=2&drtn1=05/08/2012&qryt=8&sort=10&drid1=1639&dlvl&rdct=1&star=30&subm=1&subm=1&inttkn=Dul0p4RNrlTnd61R&dsct&cmbt=2**?**dnam&tdpt1=362&ffst=0&rtmx&trtn1=362&tair1=IST&dcty=PAR&mcicid=174390028&rtmn&ddpt1=02/08/2012**?**stop_mobi=yes

what exactly this '?' does? can i use it multiple times or '&' is the only option to pass multiple parameter when '?' is already used once?

note: occurrence marked as bold.

Comment: To help the usefulness of this question:  if there is a tag for Request Parameters or Query String, I would add that.

Comment: @trante This is "what does it mean", not "can i haz 2".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `?` character in a URL signifies the start of the "request parameters", or "query string".  Additional parameters after that have to start with `&amp;`.  You can develop your own way of handling "query strings", but most programming/scripting languages I know of already have built in ways of dealing with them, so it is generally easier to use the existing tools.

Answer (score 0):

From http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Query_string

> When a server receives a request for such a page, it runs a program
>   (if configured to do so), passing the query_string unchanged to the
>   program. The question mark is used as a separator and is not part of
>   the query string.

As a result, ? should only be used once.

Comment: That part just says any subsequent question mark is part of the query string. Ampersand is also part of the query string, yet can appear multiple times. So that citation doesn't support your answer.